# How to declare reference to lambda in C++

Tags: c++, function, lambda, reference, c++14

I want to declare a function that takes as argument a function (or lambda) with a specific prototype.

The first try is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int test(int (&val)(int)) {
    return val(2);
}
int main() {
    cout << test([](int v){
        return v+100;
    });
    return 0;
}
```

witch results in `error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type 'int (&)(int)' from an rvalue of type 'main()::<lambda(int)>'`

I tried to add const specified to the type but I don't know where exactly so I tried the following that works with GCC (-std=c++14), however I suspect it is illegal since it fails with clang:

```
int test(const auto& val) {
    return val(2);
}
```

I know I can use template or function pointers or std::function to achieve the same, then please consider this a didactic question. I want to know what does GCC deduce the type of val to, in the second example above (`int test(const auto& val)`).

```
template <typename F>
int test(F val) {
    return val(2);
}

int test(int val(int)) {
    return val(2);
}

int test(std::function<int(int)> val) {
    return val(2);
}
```

Comment: Sure and they suggest to use templates or std::function, however with GCC compiler it works even without templates.

Comment: @cpplearner I think this is the only possible explanation, you should send an answer. Thank you!

Comment: [It works just fine by accepting a function pointer](http://rextester.com/JPNGG21655)  While conversion of captureless lambda to function pointer is implicit and so is conversion between function reference and function pointer, chaining these conversions together is too much.

Answer (score 3):

> I want to declare a function that takes as argument a function (or lambda) with a specific prototype.

Closures generated by *lambda expression* have a unique and anonymous type. They could also be generic *(i.e. template `operator()`)*. There is no "easy" way of declaring a function accepting lambdas with a specific prototype. Your best bet is either using a constrained template parameter with something like [`std::is_invocable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable) or using some sort of type erasure like [`function_view`](https://vittorioromeo.info/index/blog/passing_functions_to_functions.html#%60function_view%60).

Note: if your lambda is **captureless** it is implicitly convertible to a *function pointer*. E.g.

```
int test(int (*)(int)) { }

test([](int) -> int {});      // OK
test([i = 0](int) -> int {}); // compile-time error
```

---

> I want to know what does GCC deduce the type of val to, in the second example.

```
int test(int val(int))
```

...is equivalent to...

```
int test(int (*val)(int))
```

In fact, having both of them in the same scope results in a redefinition error:

```
int test(int val(int)) {
    return val(2);
}

int test(int (*val)(int)) {
    return val(2);
}
```

```
prog.cc:5:5: error: redefinition of 'test'
int test(int (*val)(int)) {
    ^
prog.cc:1:5: note: previous definition is here
int test(int val(int)) {
    ^
```

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't express myself properly, with second example I mean `int test(const auto& val)`. I don't get warnings

Comment: @biowep, auto can't be used in function parameter lists. To take any type, templates must be used - `template <typename T> int test(const T& val)`